# Nested for loop to generate random variables with differing probabilities in R

Tags: r, loops, nested

I am trying to write a for loop that generates random variables from a geometric distribution using different probability values. However, the code I write only uses the last probability in the sequence to generate the random variables, see below.

```
x <- list()
y <- list()
probs <- seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)
for (i in 1:length(probs)) {
  for (j in 1:10000) {
    x[j] <- rgeom(n=1, prob=probs[i])+1
    y[j] <- probs[i]
  }
}
```

How do I loop along the probabilities to generate 10000 RV for each probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an nested loop for that. If you just want randomly select an probability to use on the `rgeom()` function, across 10 thousand iterations, you can do something like below, using the `sample()` function to choose which prob will be used, and store the results, in a `data.frame`.

```
x <- vector(mode = "double", length = 10000)
y <- vector(mode = "double", length = 10000)

probs <- seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)

for (i in 1:10000){
 prob <- probs[sample(1:length(probs), size = 1)]
 x[i] <- rgeom(1, prob = prob)
 y[i] <- prob
}

random_values <- data.frame(
  value = x,
  prob_used = y
)
```

**Resulting this:**

```
> head(random_values)
  value prob_used
1     0       0.6
2    23       0.1
3     0       0.6
4     0       0.6
5     2       0.1
6     4       0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be:

```
    x <- list()
    y <- list()
    probs <- seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.01)
    j<-1
    for (i in 1:length(probs)) {
      x[[j]] <- rgeom(n=10000, prob=probs[i])+1
      y[[j]] <- rep(probs[i], 10000)
      j<-j+1
    }
    x<- list(unlist(x))
    y<- list(unlist(y))
```